# GitLab health endpoint before integrating code

Tags: deployment, gitlab, fastapi, health-check

I’m new to deploying ML models and I want to deploy a model that contains several modules, each of which consist of “folders” containing some data files, .py scripts and a Python notebook.

I created a project in GitLab and I’m trying to follow tutorials on FastAPI since this is what I’m gonna be using. But I’ve been told that before I start integrating the code, I need to set up a health endpoint.

I know about the request `curl "https://gitlab.example.com/-/health"`, but do I need to set up anything? Is there anything else I need to do for the project setup before doing the `requirements.txt`, building the skeleton of the application etc.?

Comment: *Git* does not have a health endpoint. Git*Lab* may offer one, but that's GitLab, not Git. (Git, by itself, does not have endpoints. It doesn't do that sort of thing.)

Comment: @torek Sorry, typo in the title, but in the post I mentioned that specific request in GitLab. But I really don’t understand how do I deal with health endpoints when setting up a project, before integrating the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depend totaly of your needs, there is no health endpoint implemented natively in fastapi.

> But I’ve been told that before I start integrating the code, I need to set up a health endpoint.

not necessarly a bad practice, you could start by listing all your futur health checks and build your route from there.

update from comment:

> But I don’t know how to implement this. I need a config file? I’m very new to this.

From what i understand you are very new to python api so you should start by following the [official fastapi user guide](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/). You can also follow [fastapi first steps](https://realpython.com/fastapi-python-web-apis/) from [this](https://realpython.com/).

Very basic one file project that run as is:

```py
# main.py

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/health")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Alive!"}
```

Remember that the above is not suitable for production, only for testing/learning purposes, to make a production api you should follow the official [advanced user guide](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/) and implement something like the following.

more advanced router:

You have [this health lib](https://github.com/Kludex/fastapi-health) for fastapi that is nice.

You can make basic checks like this:

```py
# app.routers.health.py
from fastapi import APIRouter, status, Depends
from fastapi_health import health

from app.internal.health import healthy_condition, sick_condition

router = APIRouter(
    tags=["healthcheck"],
    responses={404: {"description": "not found"}},
)


@router.get('/health', status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
def perform_api_healthcheck(health_endpoint=Depends(health([healthy_condition, sick_condition]))):
    return health_endpoint
```

```py
# app.internal.health.py
def healthy_condition():  # just for testing puposes
    return {"database": "online"}


def sick_condition():  # just for testing puposes
    return True
```

Comment: I think I only need to return the status of the app (if it runs or not), so something like @app.get(“/“) async def root(): return {“message”: “App is working”}. But I don’t know how to implement this. I need a config file? I’m very new to this.

Comment: @johnnydoe i have update the answer